# 'completerp' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseCoreWeb'

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

[error-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQZJa.png)
Please I need help with this error it appears when I try to run a flutter web app

/C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core_web-2.2.2/lib/src/firebase_core_web.dart:148:9: Error: The getter 'completerp' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseCoreWeb'.

- 'FirebaseCoreWeb' is from 'package:firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart' ('/C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core_web-2.2.2/lib/firebase_core_web.dart').
  firebase_core_web.dart:1
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'completerp'.
  completerp.complete();
  ^^^^^^^^^^
  Failed to compile application.

Comment: Somehow `C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\firebase_core_web-2.2.2\lib\firebase_core_web.dart` on your system got accidentally modified to introduce a typo (perhaps from an errant search-and-replace or from disk corruption).  Try running `flutter pub cache --repair`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.